# Can someone explain the c++ FAILED function?

Tags: c++, windows, com

I've seen a lot of example c++ code that wraps function calls in a FAILED() function/method/macro.
Could someone explain to me how this works? And if possible does anyone know a c# equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It generally checks COM function errors. But checking any function that returns a `HRESULT` is what it's meant for, specifically. `FAILED` returns a true value if the `HRESULT` value is negative, which means that the function failed ("error" or "warning" severity). Both `S_OK` and `S_FALSE` are >= 0 and so they are not used to convey an error. With "negative" I mean that the high bit is set for `HRESULT` error codes, *i.e.*, their hexadecimal representation, which can be found in, *e.g.*, winerror.h, begins with an 8, as in 0x8000FFFF.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819775.aspx) shows the half of the WinError.h include file that defines `FAILED()`. It's actually just a very simple macro, the entire definition goes like this:

```
#define FAILED(Status) ((HRESULT)(Status)<0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> And if possible does anyone know a c# equivalent?

You won't actually need that in C#, unless you're using COM objects. Most .NET functions either already return a (more or less) meaningful value (i.e. null, false) or throw an exception when they fail.

If you're directly accessing a COM object, you can define a simple Failed function that does what the macro in unwind's post does. Define that locally (protected/private), since the messy COM details shouldn't be visible in your app anyway.

In case you didn't know, there's also a SUCCEEDED macro in COM. No need to test for failure :)

Comment: Great! but what if the com method i'm calling returns void??
What can i test against in this situation?

Comment: A COM function returning void!? Where? Which one?

Comment: Am i right in thinking the managed directx library is in fact a com wrapper? or am i completely mistaken? (as almost every method returns void!!)

Comment: MDX, if I remember correctly, should not be used anymore. You may want to try XNA instead. Anyway, a function returning void most likely signals failure by throwing an exception instead.

Comment: MDX is a thin COM wrapper. So it hides actual COM details while remaining roughly equivalent to it, that may be the reason why the methods return void.

Comment: That makes sense!
Regarding the XNA comment... i feel dirty enough using managed directx so i wouldn't want to take the plunge and use a 'toy' such as XNA ;)

Comment: XNA is not really a toy. There are impressive demos out in the wild (on youtube, for example), and it even runs on XBox 360. And trust me, it's a lot more fun than MDX.